# Read secrets from openshift in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openshift, private-key

I have this yaml file in openshift and I need to read the value of the private key in my spring project si I can then create a jwt.

The yaml file is as follows:

```
kind: Secret
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: jwt-signing-keys
  namespace: test-dev
  uid: xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx
  resourceVersion: '0000000000'
  creationTimestamp: '2022-07-19T07:55:04Z'
  managedFields:
    - manager: Mozilla
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2022-07-19T07:55:04Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:data':
          .: {}
          'f:private-key': {}
          'f:public-key': {}
        'f:type': {}
data:
  private-key: xxxxx
  public-key: xxxxx
type: Opaque
```

Then I have a class that now is reading this pk from the resource path as follows but need to be changed so now this can be read from this yaml file.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtKeyProvider {

    private final ResourceUtil resourceUtil;
    private final Base64Util base64Util;

    @Getter
    private PrivateKey privateKey;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        privateKey = readKey(
                "classpath:keys/private-key.pkcs8",
                "PRIVATE",
                this::privateKeySpec,
                this::privateKeyGenerator
        );
    }

    private <T extends Key> T readKey(String resourcePath, String headerSpec, Function<String, EncodedKeySpec> keySpec, BiFunction<KeyFactory, EncodedKeySpec, T> keyGenerator) {
        try {
            String keyString = resourceUtil.asString(resourcePath);
            //TODO you can check the headers and throw an exception here if you want

            keyString = keyString
                    .replace("-----BEGIN " + headerSpec + " KEY-----", "")
                    .replace("-----END " + headerSpec + " KEY-----", "")
                    .replaceAll("\\s+", "");

            return keyGenerator.apply(KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA"), keySpec.apply(keyString));
        } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException e) {
            throw new JwtInitializationException(e);
        }
    }

    private EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec(String data) {
        return new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(base64Util.decode(data));
    }

    private PrivateKey privateKeyGenerator(KeyFactory kf, EncodedKeySpec spec) {
        try {
            return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
        } catch(InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw new JwtInitializationException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

1st: should I add this yaml to my spring project? If so, why?
2nd: how can I read this data directly from the directory in openshift?

**UPDATE:**

Now I could set the PK as an ENV variable as follows (e.g as it is longer and contains other info)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secret-example-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: secret-test-container
      image: busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "export" ]
      env:
        - name: PRIVATE_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: jwt-signing-keys
              key: private-key
```

But from here, how I continue in spring to pass the url or file from which spring should read this key. Is it an url pointing at that yaml file or what?
How I do this in the application.properties file? I still don't get it!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: add an enviroment variable in openshift pointing to the secret value. Then you can simply inject the value by using spring properties.

Comment: And how can I do that? It's my first time working with openshift

Comment: e.g. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/nodes/pods/nodes-pods-secrets.html

Answer (score 2):

pass the secret as env var, e.g.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secret-example-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: secret-test-container
      image: busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "export" ]
      env:
        - name: TEST_SECRET_USERNAME_ENV_VAR
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef: 
              name: test-secret
              key: username
```

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/nodes/pods/nodes-pods-secrets.html

Comment: Thanks! Should I include this yaml in my project folder or no?

Comment: no, it's for use with oc client

Comment: Now I was able to add the PK as an env variable to the pod. But now my question is, which route should I give to the application properties to look for in that .yaml file in openshift!??

Comment: e.g. application.properties: `your.property.path: ${YOUR_ENV_VAR}`